# How to make OpenWRT work properly in GNS3

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt, arp

No matter what I try in GNS3 to get OpenWRT to run properly, I cannot get it to properly work with other GNS components. I can connect two devices through a switch and ping back and forth, but not to the OpenWRT device, not matter what.

When I ping OWRT an ARP request can be seen, but no reply is sent. When I ping from OWRT to a device, a requests and replies can be seen, but OWRT does not register the correct Mac-Address. It is filled with all 0s instead of the actual address that was replied.

I've tried an OWRT Docker container running on the GNS3 VMWare server, VMWare VM running a GNS3-controlled instance and a VirtualBox GNS3-controlled instance. All show exactly the same behaviour and I cannot seem to find any tutorials on how to make it work... none that actually work anyway.

Running on MacOS Mojave.
VMWare Fusion 10.

Comment: OpenWRT is meant for wireless routers and therefore has bridge interfaces setup--though not 100% if this is true of x86 build if you are using that.  Weird things can happen here.  Try disabling all bridges (use shell) and ensure you are using the physical `eth0` interfaces.

Comment: I would love to see if someone answers this. I have experienced this and other bizarre bugs in GNS3 with OpenWrt. What version image are you using?

Comment: @LawrenceC Your comment did the trick. If you will post it as an answer, I will credit you with answering the question. What can be done is 1 - to add additional ports and use those and leave eth0 alone. Or 2 - comment out anything for eth0 / lan where it says type 'bridge' and proto 'static' (don't know if the proto needed to be commented out, but it worked for me) and reboot

Comment: Actually, I wasn't able to connect anything to the internet via eth0 or eth1. If you just stick with adding new ports and working with those, so far all is ok. Although I haven't tested that much yet